# How can I serialize a nested object with singleton values to JSON in R?

Tags: json, r

How I can use jsonlite's `toJSON()` function to produce the following JSON?

```
{"data":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

I'm new to R. I was able to produce the following, but "bar" is inside an array which I don't want:

```
> library(jsonlite)
> toJSON(list(data=list(foo = "bar")))
{"data":{"foo":["bar"]}}
```

I can't figure out how to get "bar" out of the array, and I can't find an obvious analog to a hashmap/dictionary in the examples of toJSON I've found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can acheive that with the `auto_unbox` argument.  See `?toJSON` for more info.

```
> toJSON(list(data=list(foo = "bar")),auto_unbox = TRUE)
{"data":{"foo":"bar"}}
```